# SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am new to SSRS. I use SSRS to access a remote data source. I can use the interface shown below to build and execute queries and produce reports:

[image]

Is there a way to build a report by specifying the SQL directly rather than using the graphical tools. I have spent some time Googling this and I have gone through a few tutorials. I am unable to find an answer.

Comment: There are several ways - see [Query Design Tools in Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345246(v=sql.90).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the `Edit as Text` button in the top left-hand corner of that window and have at it.

[image: SSRS Query Designer]

**Edit** If you are only seeing XML in the query window, then you are using a [Report Model data source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239359.aspx) instead of a direct database connection. Models cannot be queried directly with SQL.

In order to query with SQL, setup a [Data Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450.aspx) using a connection string that points directly your database.

Comment: @w0051977 Then you're building a query off of a [Report Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239359.aspx) data source instead of a direct database connection. Models cannot be queried directly with SQL.

Comment: Thanks, +1.  @Bluefeet provided a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345246(v=sql.90).aspx.  Please confirm that these will not work with a Report Model.  Then I will be able to mark this question as answered.

Comment: @w0051977 Bluefeet's link is good, but he was operating under the same assumption I was when I posted the answer. If you look further down on that page, the `Report Model Query Designer` is all you're able to work with, given the model data source. Report Models cannot be directly queried with SQL.